# Trivial require throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to work with a [popular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electrolyte) dependency injection library, [electrolyte](https://github.com/jaredhanson/electrolyte), but even a trivial script requiring it throws an error. I can't find any discussion or [issues](https://github.com/jaredhanson/electrolyte/issues) related to my error, but since I'm new to node, I'd like to check that I'm not doing something obviously wrong before appealing to the author.

Install electrolyte:

```
npm install electrolyte
```

Run this 1-line app, `test.js`, with node:

```
var di = require("electrolyte");
```

Get this error:

```
util.js:555
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
                      ^
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null
    at Function.create (native)
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:555:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/tmp/node_modules/electrolyte/lib/container.js:42:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/tmp/node_modules/electrolyte/lib/index.js:1:79)
```

I've tried this in two environments (node on ubuntu from packages, mac from brew) with identical results. I can install and require other libraries without issue. Versions of node and electrolyte appear to be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the versions of node I had through brew and through debian packages were pretty old. Following the [installation guide](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) to add node's own debian repository corrected the problem.

Comment: But How to port this to node v0.10.25 ?